# Add column to CSV File from another CSV File (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

For example:

**Persons.csv**

```
name, last_name
-----------------------
jack, jack_lastName
luc, luc_lastname
```

**FileExample.csv**

```
id
243
123
```

**Result:**

```
name, last_name, exampleId
-------------------------------
jack, jack_lastName, 243
luc, luc_lastname, 123
```

I want to aggregate any number of columns from another data source, to insert that final result in a file or in a database table.

I have been trying many ways but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make use of Mergefiles in azure data factory pipeline to merge two csv files .

Select copydata activity and go to source to loop through wild card entry *.csv to search for csv files  in storage(configure linked storage to adf in this process).

[image]

Then the create a output csv in the same container if required as in my case to merge files and store by naming it some examplemerge.csv.

[image]

Check mark the first row as header.

validate and try to debug .

Then you must be able to see merged files in the resultant merged file in output folder.
[image]

You can check this **reference** [vlog Merge Multiple CSV files to single CSV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUqRyW2jmmY) for more details and also this   [vlog on Load Multiple CSV Files to a Table in Azure Data Factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJYBos1o0sQ)  if required.

But if you want to join the files , there must be some common column to join.
Also check this thread from Q&A [Azure Data Factory merge 2 csv files with different schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/542994/azure-data-factory-merge-2-csv-files-with-differen.html)